# Delete function not working?

Tags: php

I am wondering why this code does not work? The button does the right confirmation sequence but the record does not actually delete. I copied and pasted the code from a working button and I think in the transfer I have missed specifying a detail?

```
if (isset($_GET['deleteseries'])) {
    echo 'Do you really want to delete ' 
        . $_GET['series'] 
        . '? <a  href="editstock.php?yesdelete=' 
        . $_GET['id'] 
        . '">Yes</a> | <a href="editstock.php">No</a>';
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
    $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM series WHERE id='%s' LIMIT 1",
        GetSQLValueString($_GET['yesdelete'], "int"));

    mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
    header("location: editstock.php"); 
    exit();
}
```

With this button:

```
<input name="deleteseries" 
    type="button" id="deleteseries" 
    value="delete" 
    style="width:20%; float:right" 
    onclick="window.location.href = '?deleteseries=delete&id=<?php echo $row_seriesrecordset['id']; ?>&series=<?php echo $row_seriesrecordset['series']; ?>'"/>
```

Comment: Sounds like a database error as opposed to a php one. Have you echoed the mysql errors?

Comment: the errors usually do echo but this one simply goes back to the page without deleting...do you want me to paste the working button so you can see what i wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to debug output `$deleteSQ`?

Comment: how would i do that? and i dont see what is wrong there?

Comment: `echo "The database query is: >>".$deleteSQ."<<\n"`. You can then look, if the id was inserted correctly. You should further debug output `echo mysql_error();`  after the query to see, if errors occured.

Comment: ive gone to phpmyadmin to check and nothing changes? the delete button is tied with an update form that has been working the same as other functioning forms so i dont think its the id itself?

Comment: @Sean could you please have a look and tell me why you think the new button i have created is not working like the previous one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
    $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM series WHERE id='%s' LIMIT 1",
        GetSQLValueString($_GET['yesdelete'], "int"));

    mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "deleted entry with ID ".$_GET['yesdelete'];
    exit;
    header("location: editstock.php"); 
    exit();
}
```

what does it say that entry was deleted? Maybe youre passing the wrong "yesdelete" parameter (wrong ID)..

Comment: no...that didnt work just a the previous and youre echo didnt show to say that it was deleted...what would the right yesdelete parameter be?

Comment: is it because i am using too much of the same information for two different buttons?

Comment: if i paste the working button would it be easier for you to compare?

Comment: please please help! do you need more code so you know what makes the other one work? i cant see a difference and i definitely think its the last parse section as you were trying...

Answer (score -2):

Everything is correct, just a small mistake you made in the following code:

```
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
    $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM series WHERE id='. $_GET['yesdelete'] LIMIT 1",
        GetSQLValueString($_GET['yesdelete'], "int"));

    mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
    header("location: editstock.php"); 
    exit();
}
```

Comment: the sprintf is now completely wrong. also, sql injection would be possible if the string were correctly formed

Comment: thankyou but it now says there is a syntax error in that code...?

Comment: the %s is the standard for the rest of my code as opposed the other insert variable you suggested and works as a reference in the working button...?